# Populate a div with specific info from a checkbox

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, title

I'm try to get when I click on a specified check box that it will replace the text within my specified div with the label of the checkbox and if more then one checkbox is checked it will place them with a , and if the text is to long it with put up the the amount followed by ...

my html looks as:

```
<div style="cursor:pointer" id="st"><div id="txtst">&#9660; No Preference</div>
</div><div id="divst" style="display:none;font-size:smaller">
<input type="checkbox" name="s1" value="S"> <label for="s1">Repairs</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="s2" value="I"> <label for="s2">Orders</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="s3" value="M"> <label for="s3">Technician</label><br>
```

and my js as:

```
$(function(){
    $('#lf').click(function () {
        $('#divlf').toggle();
    });
    $('#st').click(function () {
        $('#divst').toggle();
    });
});
$(function(){
    $('#divst').click(function() {
        if ( $(input[checkbox]).length > 0) {
            $("#txtst").hide();
        } else {
            $("#txtst").show();
        }
    }); 
});
```

I know this js isn't complete right as far as the checkbox function as it was another example I seen on here but was nowhere near answered correctly.

Comment: I have them on my page, I just wrote out the basic example real quick sorry.

Comment: Please add them to the example HTML, so we can help...Plus, you need to be clear as to what `div` you are trying to insert the label's text into

Comment: I would like to add it to #txtst, but the example I found it just showed it hiding that div. And I've added the labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').delegate('input:checkbox', 'change', function() {
        var txt = "";
        $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(i) {
            if (txt) { txt += ","; }
            txt += $(this).next().text();

            // see if txt is too long
            if (txt.length > 50)
            {
               txt = txt.substring(0, 47) + "...";
               return false; // stop the each() loop
            }
        });
        if (!txt) { txt = "No Preference"; }
        $('#txtst').text(txt);
    });
});
```

This will work if you really have labels following your checkboxes like so:

```
<input type='checkbox' id='cb1'><label>Checkbox 1</label><br />
<input type='checkbox' id='cb2'><label>Checkbox 2</label><br />
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I am looking for, but how would I have it to only work of a certain set of checkboxes, and then display the label into the txt ?

Comment: @NexxeuS - duh yeah you are right.  I just changed it to grab the text from the element right after the checkbox.  Will work if he really has labels immediately following each checkbox...

Comment: @Bobby - add a special class to those checkboxes (<input class='groupA' type='checkbox'...>, such as "groupA", then change "input:checkbox" to "input.groupA:checkbox" both places in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
    if(!$("input[type='checkbox']").length > 0){
        $("#divst").html( $("label[for='"+$(this).html()+"']") );
    } else {
        $("#divst").html("You Have No Preference");
    }
});
```

For this to work for a special set of checkboxes, you need to add `class="group_1"` to your checkboxes, and replace `"input[type='checkbox']"` with `.group_1`.